# Is there a way to detect if a session is being accessed by more than one person?

Tags: php, security, session

Given the circumstance of session fixation/hijacking, how to detect if the same session is being simultaneously accessed by multiple parties?

I prefer not to use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Comment: You could also use the user agent

Comment: @Naveed if you are going to feverishly edit questions, please also pull out the "Thanks" and "Thanks in Advance" and "In PHP" in the title.  Always endeavor to do a "full edit".

Comment: @mickmackusa OK i will take care.

Comment: What do you mean with "multiple parties"? Which specific use case(s) are you trying to detect?

Comment: @ Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans By "multiple parties", I mean the user and attackers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't, because the HTTP protocol is a stateless protocol which means the server knows nothing about the user after the request is completed.

But you can try a few tricks to make it harder to spoof a session from an unauthorized user, common technique from the server side is to store a hash of the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] on the session variable and compare it with what you get at every request, killing the session if the information changes.

Don't use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] or other means to guess the client IP as it break's the sessions for mobile users because their IP is always changing.

Comment: If two users have the same OS and browser configuration, then their $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']  value will be the same right?

Comment: yes, but each user will have a unique cookie, so chances are pretty good that the cookie+browser combination is a safe enough bet ( it will block someone for example copying the cookie to another machine or to another browser )